Need help to standardize function name from __FUNCTION__, __FUNCSIG__ and __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
I need help to finish a function name parser/standardizer in C++.
I'd like to read and return a simplified but still meaningfull function name while keeping my logs small. My issue is that I need a static storage, maybe with the help of a template struct, but I never really understood how to do it and I'm quite stuck now.
Here's the code:
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

constexpr std::string_view ClangFunctionNameSubStringNameStart(std::string_view functionName, std::string_view prettyFunctionName)
{
    int nested = 0;
    auto nameBegin = prettyFunctionName.length() - functionName.length();
    while(--nameBegin > 0)
    {
        const auto c = prettyFunctionName[nameBegin];
        if (c == ')' || c == '>')
            ++nested;
        else if (c == '(' ||c == '<')
            --nested;

        if (nested == 0 && (c == ' ' || c == '*'))
        {
            ++nameBegin;
            break;
        }
    }

    return prettyFunctionName.substr(nameBegin);
}

constexpr std::string_view ClangFunctionNameSubStringNameStop(std::string_view prettyFunctionName)
{
    auto templateBegin = prettyFunctionName.rfind(']');
    if (templateBegin != std::string::npos)
    {
        for (int nested = 1; nested > 0;)
        {
            --templateBegin;
            if (prettyFunctionName[templateBegin] == ']')
                ++nested;
            else if (prettyFunctionName[templateBegin] == '[')
                --nested;
        }
    }

    auto nameEnd = prettyFunctionName.rfind(')', templateBegin);
    if (nameEnd != std::string::npos)
    {
        for (int nested = 1; nested > 0;)
        {
            --nameEnd;
            if (prettyFunctionName[nameEnd] == ')')
                ++nested;
            else if (prettyFunctionName[nameEnd] == '(')
                --nested;
        }
    }

    return prettyFunctionName.substr(0, nameEnd);
}

constexpr std::string_view ClangFunctionNameTrim(std::string_view functionName, std::string_view prettyFunctionName)
{
    return ClangFunctionNameSubStringNameStart(functionName, ClangFunctionNameSubStringNameStop(prettyFunctionName));
}

constexpr std::size_t ClangFunctionNameComputeLength(std::string_view functionName, std::string_view prettyFunctionName) {
    std::size_t length = 0;
    int nested = 0;

    constexpr auto anonymous_class = std::string_view{ "(anonymous class)::operator()" };
    constexpr auto anonymous_class_namespace = std::string_view{ "::(anonymous class)::operator()" };

    auto input = ClangFunctionNameTrim(functionName, prettyFunctionName);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
        // Détection de `::(anonymous class)::operator()` ou `(anonymous class)::operator()`
        if (nested == 0 && i + (anonymous_class_namespace.length() - 1) < input.length() && input.substr(i, anonymous_class_namespace.length()) == anonymous_class_namespace) {
            i += anonymous_class_namespace.length() - 1; // Avancer pour sauter `::(anonymous class)::operator()`
        }
    else if (nested == 0 && i + (anonymous_class.length() - 1) < input.length() && input.substr(i, anonymous_class.length()) == anonymous_class) {
            length += anonymous_class.length() - 1;
        }
        else if (input[i] == '<' || input[i] == '(') {
            ++nested;
        }
        else if (input[i] == '>' || input[i] == ')') {
            --nested;
        }
        else if (nested == 0) {
            ++length;
        }
    }
    return length;
}

template<size_t N>
constexpr auto ClangFunctionNameClean(std::string_view functionName, std::string_view prettyFunctionName) {
    std::array<char, N+1> result{};
    std::size_t index = 0;
    int nested = 0;

    constexpr auto anonymous_class = std::string_view{ "(anonymous class)::operator()" };
    constexpr auto anonymous_class_namespace = std::string_view{ "::(anonymous class)::operator()" };

    auto input = ClangFunctionNameTrim(functionName, prettyFunctionName);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
        if (nested == 0 && i + (anonymous_class_namespace.length() - 1) < input.length() && input.substr(i, anonymous_class_namespace.length()) == anonymous_class_namespace) {
            i += anonymous_class_namespace.length() - 1;
        }
    else if (nested == 0 && i + (anonymous_class.length() - 1) < input.length() && input.substr(i, anonymous_class.length()) == anonymous_class) {
            for (std::size_t j = 0; j < anonymous_class.length(); ++j)
                result[index++] = input[i++];
        }
        else if (input[i] == '<' || input[i] == '(') {
            ++nested;
        }
        else if (input[i] == '>' || input[i] == ')') {
            --nested;
        }
        else if (nested == 0) {
            result[index++] = input[i];
        }
    }
    result[index] = '\0';
    return result;
}

constexpr std::size_t ClangHash(const char* input, size_t len) { return (len > 0 ? static_cast<std::size_t>(*input) + 33 * ClangHash(input + 1, len - 1) : 5381); }

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t ClangFunctionNameHash(std::array<char, N> const& storage)
{
    return ClangHash(storage.data(), storage.size());
}

template<std::size_t H, std::size_t N>
struct ClangFunctionNameStorage
{
    constexpr static std::array<char, N> storage;
};

#if !defined(__clang__) && (defined(WIN64) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(__MINGW64__) || defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__MINGW32__))
    #define FUNCTION_NAME __FUNCTION__
#else
    #define FUNCTION_NAME __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
#endif

#define CLANG_TEST ClangFunctionNameClean<ClangFunctionNameComputeLength(__FUNCTION__, FUNCTION_NAME)>(__FUNCTION__, FUNCTION_NAME).data()

auto lambdaGlobalNamespace = []() {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "|" << FUNCTION_NAME << "|" << CLANG_TEST << std::endl;
};

template<typename T>
struct Test2
{
public:
    void Titi()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "|" << FUNCTION_NAME << "|" << CLANG_TEST << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename U>
    auto Foo() -> auto
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "|" << FUNCTION_NAME << "|" << CLANG_TEST << std::endl;
        return 5;
    }
};

struct Test
{
public:
    void* Titi(int a)
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "|" << FUNCTION_NAME << "|" << CLANG_TEST << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }

    template<typename T>
    void* Toto(int a, int b) const
    {
        auto x = [this](){};
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "|" << FUNCTION_NAME << "|" << CLANG_TEST << std::endl;
    Test2<int> t;
    t.Titi();
    t.Foo<decltype(x)>();
        return nullptr;
    }

    template<typename T>
    void* Tata(int a, int b)
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "|" << FUNCTION_NAME << "|" << CLANG_TEST << std::endl;

        [this]()
        {
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "|" << FUNCTION_NAME << "|" << CLANG_TEST << std::endl;
        }();

        [this]()
        {
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "|" << FUNCTION_NAME << "|" << CLANG_TEST << std::endl;
        }();

        return nullptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr const char clang1Function[] = "Titi";
    constexpr const char clang1Pretty[] = "void *Test::Titi(int)";
    constexpr const char clang1Expected[] = "Test::Titi";

    constexpr const char clang2Function[] = "Tata";
    constexpr const char clang2Pretty[] = "void *Test::Tata(int, int) [T = float]";
    constexpr const char clang2Expected[] = "Test::Tata";

    constexpr const char clang3Function[] = "operator()";
    constexpr const char clang3Pretty[] = "auto Test::Tata(int, int)::(anonymous class)::operator()() const";
    constexpr const char clang3Expected[] = "Test::Tata";

    constexpr const char clang4Function[] = "main";
    constexpr const char clang4Pretty[] = "int main()";
    constexpr const char clang4Expected[] = "main";

    constexpr const char clang5Function[] = "Toto";
    constexpr const char clang5Pretty[] = "void *Test::Toto(int, int) const [T = Test]";
    constexpr const char clang5Expected[] = "Test::Toto";

    constexpr const char clang6Function[] = "Titi";
    constexpr const char clang6Pretty[] = "void Test2<int>::Titi() [T = int]";
    constexpr const char clang6Expected[] = "Test2::Titi";

    constexpr const char clang7Function[] = "Foo";
    constexpr const char clang7Pretty[] = "auto Test2<int>::Foo() [T = int, U = (lambda at main.cpp:40:18)]";
    constexpr const char clang7Expected[] = "Test2::Foo";

    constexpr const char clang8Function[] = "operator()";
    constexpr const char clang8Pretty[] = "auto (anonymous class)::operator()() const";
    constexpr const char clang8Expected[] = "(anonymous class)::operator()";

    Test test;

    test.Titi(1);
    test.Toto<Test>(1,2);
    test.Tata<float>(1,2);

    lambdaGlobalNamespace();

    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "|" << FUNCTION_NAME << "|" << CLANG_TEST << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

The output is correct, now I'd like to transform my cleaned function names into a static storage so that my compiled code is not bloated with the __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ content.
Of course, I'd like a constexpr.
